# Why do I get only +2 for an upvote?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm shocked :-)
While an upvote for an answer usually is awarded with 10 points, for one answer I only got +2. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Can you link to the answer?  How did you determine that you only received +2?

Comment: @Kevin - it shows on my rep history. I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You hit the daily reputation cap - in every 24-hour period, the system will allow you to gain at most 200 reputation points from up-votes. For various obscure accounting reasons, you were 2 points shy of 200 when that vote was cast, hence it gave you +2 instead of the normal +10. You also got +0 for several up-votes following that...

If you check [your reputation page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/2064/stevenvh?tab=reputation), you'll see a break-out of all these votes (you can also check your [rep audit page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/reputation) for a more detailed run-down of how your reputation is calculated and capped).

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense to me.  I've seen this mention of the 200 point/day cap, but I've definitely gotten more than 200 points several days.  What's the point of the cap though?  It says that answers should not be considered as worthy if they are clumped in time near other worthy answers.  That doesn't make a lot of sense, especially since time to write good answers comes in spurts, making it likely that several good answers are clumped.  I don't get it, especially since 200 isn't that hard to hit with a few good answers.  I guess I should only write one good answer per day?

Comment: @Olin: you got more than 200 points today too... The cap is 200 points *from up-votes*. The +15 from getting an answer accepted, +2 for accepting an answer, or +whatever for being awarded a bounty aren't capped. There are users who routinely exceed the cap by a huge margin, simply by posting answers that get accepted! As for the reasons... [See the responses to this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap) - it's an effort to smooth out some of the problems that can arise from gaining too much rep too quickly.

Comment: +1 that rep audit page is cool, what other semi-hidden content is there?